# how to pass a java object to oracle stored procedure with following details

Tags: java, database, oracle, logging, stored-procedures

I have my ORACLE table with structure as

```
desc extraction_log1
           Name                           Null                        
                                                     Type                                                                                                                                                                                          

 ------------------------------ -------- ------------------------------------------------------------     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      ----------------------------- 
 ROW_NUM                        NOT NULL            NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
DATE_TIME                                        TIMESTAMP(8)                                                                                                                                                                                  
USER_NAME                                         VARCHAR2(32)                                                                                                                                                                                  
PLATFORM_NAME                                      VARCHAR2(20)                                                                                                                                                                                  
R_OBJECT_ID                                       VARCHAR2(16)
```

Then I created an object type in oracle as

```
create or replace type EXTRACTION_LOG_TYPE as object    (          

 USER_NAME VARCHAR2(32), 
 R_OBJECT_ID VARCHAR2(16), 

  );
```

Then I created procedure in a package as

```
create or replace package body PAC_BEAN is 
  --The insert procedure will receive EXTRACTION_LOG_TYPE and put it into table EXTRACTION_LOG1.  

   procedure PRO_INSERT_LOG(ELT in EXTRACTION_LOG_TYPE) is 

   begin 

      insert into EXTRACTION_LOG1 ( R_OBJECT_ID, USER_NAME)
           values (ELT.R_OBJECT_ID, ELT.USER_NAME);  

      commit;  

 exception  

  when others then 
    rollback;  

  end PRO_INSERT_LOG;  
  end PAC_BEAN;
```

and coming to my java side I have declared a bean with

```
public class ExtractionLogType {        
        //Name declared in Oracle        
   public static final String ORACLE_OBJECT_NAME = "EXTRACTION_LOG_TYPE";            
   //The attributes        
  private String  R_OBJECT_ID;        
  private String USER_NAME;      
  //setters and getters      
  public  String getR_OBJECT_ID() {
    return R_OBJECT_ID;
  }
  public  void setR_OBJECT_ID(String rOBJECTID) {
    R_OBJECT_ID = rOBJECTID;
    }
  public  String getUSER_NAME() {
    return USER_NAME;
   }
  public  void setUSER_NAME(String uSERNAME) {
    USER_NAME = uSERNAME;
   }


            }
```

in my Class containing main

```
               import java.sql.CallableStatement;
               import java.sql.Connection;
                 import java.sql.DriverManager;
               import java.sql.SQLException;

            public class DBLogger{     
          String dbUrl;     
        Connection con;      
     //constructor for creation of  connection object 
        as and when an object of DBLogger is instantiated     
        public DBLogger(){           
    dbUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin@my url";        
         try {             
        //load Oracle Driver class             
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");     
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();         
            System.err.println("Oracle driver class not found");       
            }      
        try {         
            //instantiate connection object       
            con = DriverManager.getConnectio (dbUrl,"userId","pwd");                
            } catch (SQLException e) {      
                e.printStackTrace();                       
              System.err.println("Connection object to oracle cant be established");   
                }    
            } 
        public static void main(String args[]){  
     try{
    DBLogger db=new DBLogger();        
    CallableStatement cs = null;        
    ExtractionLogType elt=new  ExtractionLogType();         
    elt.setR_OBJECT_ID("79479479A900");       
    elt.setUSER_NAME("Jeevan");               
    cs = db.con.prepareCall("{call PAC_BEAN.PRO_INSERT_LOG(?)}");                
    /*                     
     * *code to insert the above object into our Database               
     *       
    */
    cs.execute();           
    System.out.println("insert procedure executed successfully");                  
    db.con.close();      
    }  //end try  
catch (SQLException e) {      
    e.printStackTrace();   }     
catch(Exception e) {             e.printStackTrace();        
}   
}

       }
```

I can't figure out the code to make the object get inserted into my database.
can anyone suggest me regarding this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define a array descriptor for your database type, this example could help you:

```
final ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("EXTRACTION_LOG_TYPE", con);
// create an Object Array
Object[] data = new Object[2];
// set the values in order of appearance
data[0] = elt.getUSER_NAME();
data[1] = elt.getR_OBJECT_ID();
// Create the Array
ARRAY array = new ARRAY(descriptor, con, data);
// put it on your statement
cs.setArray(1, array);
// execute ...
```

Comment: getting error as  " Fail to construct descriptor: Unable to resolve type: "SYSTEM.EXTRACTION_LOG_TYPE" "

Comment: i have that in my database but throwing this exception.

Comment: @Jeevan Is the type EXTRACTION_LOG_TYPE part of the schema SYSTEM? Where do you create the type? In a package?

Comment: @Jeevan may be it works with ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("SYSTEM.EXTRACTION_LOG_TYPE", con);

Comment: No Luck. Still the same exception

Answer (score 0):

This is terrible idea to create any objects in SYSTEM schema of the database. It is the same bad idea to connect your app straight to this scheme either. 
This looks like a lack of privileges disallowing you to get what you want. Create new schema, dedicated user of this schema and then create all required object using this new user (it will be the owner of your objects). This way you can avoid "issue" where you cannot access something you supposed to have an access to.